Configuring-ROS2-Environment
I am going about setting up ROS2 for the first time, and when I enter the command
set | findstr -i ROS

the output I receive is
cmdlet Set-Variable at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name[0]:

I am new to using this library but did not have any complications when going about the initial install to my knowledge, and I could not find anything online on the matter. Any information would be greatly appreciated!

You are following this guide, 3 Check environment variables, and running on Windows, presumably.
It seems that you are running the set command in a PowerShell window.  PowerShell has a set-variable command (plus an alias named just set). However, the PowerShell syntax differs from the set command in cmd. As an example, compare help set in PowerShell vs. set /? in cmd.
The solution is to open a CMD window instead (i.e. go to the Windows tab and type CMD then enter).
Now, at the command prompt on the CMD window, type set | findstr -i ROS
The command should now work as expected, and as described in the tutorial.
